# "update-secureboot-policy --enroll-key" running on every new startup eating resources

Tags: debian, operating-systems, secure-boot

`update-secureboot-policy --enroll-key` seems to run whenever I start my computer and never stops running unless I manually kill the process. It makes my computer hot and uses lots of system resources. If I manually kill it the computer cools down and everything is fine. What exactly is going on here? It seems like it's being called by perl which is calling debconf frontend which is calling update-secureboot-policy, hence : `/usr/bin/perl -w /usr/share/debconf/frontend /usr/sbin/update-secureboot-policy --enroll-key`

EDIT:

I am using ElementaryOS 5.0 Which is based on Ubuntu 18.04

[image: usage statistics of update-secureboot-policy]

Comment: Just disable Secure Boot in UEFI settings. It's not that process what's making it hot. Probably you have Nvidia graphics but the drivers aren't being loaded due to Secure Boot and that's the reason why that process appears - it enables users to sign the drivers. But again, the easiest option is to disable Secure Boot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I only have integrated intel graphics.

Comment: There are other unsigned drivers. Some wifi drivers, for example.

Comment: The suggestion from @user921000 works for me, though I have to turn Secure Boot back off, at least some of the time, when I install updates.

Comment: Did anybody ever find out where the call `usr/bin/perl -w /usr/share/debconf/frontend /usr/sbin/update-secureboot-policy --enroll-key` comes from? It was running on my machine, but I can not find out what did start it.

Answer (score 19):

I had same problem and I found a solution, actually it was quite easy.

The problem was that a script was waiting on me to confirm for adding an UEFI entry on my computer but the terminal was not showing up and consuming all ressources (active waiting ?)

**Brief**

My solution was to run manually the command line, restart the computer and enroll the MOK key.

**Complete explication**

1. Get the actual command copy-pastable

   `ps aux | grep -e "update-secureboot-policy"`
2. Stop the current process

   `sudo kill <pid>`
3. Run manually the command and follow UEFI instructions

   `sudo /usr/bin/perl -w /usr/share/debconf/frontend /usr/sbin/update-secureboot-policy --enroll-key`
4. Reboot the computer and in the bios go to "MOK key" management
5. Enroll the key (see image below)
6. Finish

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! I have been trying to fix this for a while now.. Really annoying

Comment: You are welcome ! :)